Fantasy manga about a male adventurer who gifts his female companion with a dagger, unaware that doing so is a proposal in this world
The story has a male main character who is an adventurer in a fantasy world. He gets followed by a female from another country who asks him to party with her. After a little while, he presents her a gift which is a dagger, unaware that, in that world, doing that is a proposal. She accepts the dagger, and they continue adventuring a bit.
After a major monster subjugation, he is found out to be really strong, and possibly a hero. His female companion warns him about keeping the fact that he is a hero from the country a secret for his own safety. After visiting the capital, it is found out that he is a hero, and they track him by using runes on a dagger that they give him as a gift. They send out a group to dispose of him but end up killing his female companion. He ends up killing all but one attacker and is stopped by the same female companion he thought was dead. Turns out she had an artifact they found that negated a one-time fatal blow.

I recommend visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions to find some guidance on additional things to [edit] into your question.

Do you remember what he did to be transported to another world? His hair color? Does he have a "system" where he gets a user interface for his powers? If so, is that a common thing in this world? What's the magic system like?

@Nathan: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Your question has been closed as a duplicate. This is not a censure, but merely part of how we tie story-identification questions together once accepted. You will still get points for upvotes and people can leave comments, but the question won't receive any new answers unless re-opened. Congrats on finding your work!

If Valorum is right, this may be a duplicate of Isekai where man proposes to women with a dagger and he had no idea what it means where the answer was A 29-Year-Old Bachelor, Transported To A New World To Live Freely... At Least He Wanted To

After making a lot of money on an unexpectedly dangerous quest that also brought them closer together, isekai protagonist Taishi takes his teammate-turned-lover Marle shopping for better gear. He notices her admiring an expensive mythril shortsword, and ends up buying it for her while she's distracted. Later that day, during a date, he presents it to her, and although she's hesitant to take it at first, after a little convincing, she happily accepts it, and Taishi is surprised when the people nearby start applauding and congratulating them. When they return to their inn, the innkeeper's wife spots it and recalls when her husband gave her a mythril shortsword, prompting Taishi to ask if gifting a mythril shortsword has any special meaning. After a bit of stunned silence, Marle starts crying. Taishi has been hiding the fact that he was actually summoned from another world, and this is his first time hearing that in this world, it's common knowledge that when a man gives a mythril sword or dagger to a woman, he's promising to keep her safe if she'll agree to belong to him alone. After returning to their room, Taishi gently explains that he didn't realize he was proposing marriage so it didn't count, then devastates her by taking the mythril shortsword out of her hands... and presents it to her again.


"If Valorum is right" - lol.
